# How to remove invisible junk characters from a XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read some xml files.

when i am opening these files with notepad/wordpad/MS Word or any Browser, it is opening in its original form.But when i tried to execute it with MS DOS, an invisible chacter like "**∩╗┐**" is seen.
I think '**∩╗┐**' is creating an error.i am finding the error  “Content is not allowed in prolog.”

Please tell me how can i remove this invisible junk characters from xml file using C# code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a byte order mark?

Comment: Execute XML? In MS-DOS? Do you mean you print it in a console window?

Comment: I dont know what is it?It is invisible in all browsers and almost all editors but it is seen in MS Dos window.when i typed 
C:>type test.xml

Comment: @VipinTyagi `type` is an ASCII tool... so: don't use that? Also: I **seriously** doubt that you have a working version of MS DOS. That died along with Windows 95 (maybe Windows ME?)...

Comment: Developing in Dosbox ;-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be the [UTF-8 byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Many text editors (for example Notepad++ and jEdit) allow you specify whether the BOM should be written for UTF-8 or not. With Windows Notepad your only option is to save the file as ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

Sure sounds like a byte-order mark. Your question is unclear, but if actually do need to write these files from C# without a byte-order mark, you can specify this by passing `false` to the `UTF8Encoding` constructor:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = your_xml_document;
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output_filename, new UTF8Encoding(false))
{  
    xmlDoc.Save(writer);
}
```