# Hidden junk characters in XML files

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove invisible junk characters from a XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930709/how-to-remove-invisible-junk-characters-from-a-xml-file)

I am getting these(**∩╗┐**) type of hidden junk characters in my xml files.How can I remove these using C# code.

I have so many xml files like this.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Hidden junk" doesn't sound too good. Maybe you should look into what's generating the junk instead of ignoring it and removing it? Otherwise I suggest looking for a pattern in the junk and deciding when it is valid and when it is invalid. Then find the invalid stuff and delete it. It may or may not benefit you to parse the XML vs read the raw text.

Comment: I have written these xml files in simple text editors like notepad.some of these are running very well,while some xml files are executing with ∩╗┐ type of hidden characters.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to write Unicode data but saving it as ANSI text? That might explain the weird characters

Comment: If they are in the beginning of the files then they are probably the BOM (Byte Order Mark). Use `XDocument.Load` to properly read the XML files.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Yes they are in the beginning of the files and they are BOM.Is there any way to remove these?Please tell me.

Comment: Please anyone tell me the solution.

Comment: If they're a BOM, then they aren't characters at all, the problem is you're looking at it in something that doesn't realise they're BOM. How are you reading these XML?